# CodedUI Test- Mouse.Click() on control dose not give expected outcome

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I am using Visual studio 2010 to create CodedUI Scripts.The application under Test is a web based Loan origination application .

I am automating a part where  user enter's zip code and clicks on search.
when I enter zip code manually and click on search the response is received  instantly.

But when the same is done with code,Zip code is successfully sent and search button is clicked but application dose not respond.

```
Mouse.Click(ContactInformation.ContactInformationForm.PropertyAddress.ImageZipLookup);
```

Just wanted to understand if this is a playback issue and is there a alternative for using mouse.click()

Comment: Could very well be that the control is not ready to receive clicks. Just to debug this, add a slight delay before the click and see if that helps. Also if the control is off the page (due to scrolling) call EnsureClickable prior to clicking.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the definition for the submit button is incorrect in your recording.  Open the .uitest file, find the control in question in the tree, and open the SearchProperties in the properties of the control.  Verify that against the source on the page, and then try again.  It's possible that the recording identified a parent HtmlDiv object or something that's receiving the input rather than the button itself (or link, if that's the case).

Personally, while I'm looking at the SearchProperties, I'd remove any properties that are unnecessary.  If there's an ID or unique class for the object in question, I'd stick with that alone rather than identifying six or seven other traits that may not be correct on each run (.css styles, inner text, etc. can change depending on your app).

Just be sure you edit the SearchProperties in the UI rather than the text editor, as the .designer.cs file is recreated each time you run the Test Builder, so you would lose any changes you make directly to that file.

Comment: I dont think there is any issue with identification of the control,the fact that its clicking on the required control shows that.issue is that response is  not displayed when the scenario is automated.

Comment: Sorry, I misread that the control was confirmed.  If a response isn't being displayed, you might try looking at the browser debugger and see what network traffic is being sent.  Possible something on the page is holding up execution, like a tracker or something?